# Vue2 populate inputs in edit view

Tags: vuejs2

I´m trying to create a simple CRUD in vue2 and works perfectly, but when i enter in edit view i need to fill form inputs based on Firebase data.

View

```
  <v-text-field prepend-icon="person" v-model="user" name="user" label="User" type="text" required></v-text-field>
  <v-text-field prepend-icon="mail" v-model="email" name="email" label="Email" type="email"></v-text-field>
```

JS

```
  export default {
    data: function () {
      return {
        user: '',
        email: '',
        drawer: null
      }
      var edit = ref.child(this.$route.params.id)
      edit.on('value', function (snapshot) {
        this.user = snapshot.val().name
        this.email = snapshot.val().email
      })
```

> snapshot.val().name

Return name properly but when i try to assign this value to this.user does not work. Console does not return any error.

¿Anybody has a idea whats is the correct way?

Answer (score 0):

```
export default {
data: function () {
  return {
    user: '',
    email: '',
    drawer: null
  }
  var edit = ref.child(this.$route.params.id)
  var self = this;
  edit.on('value', function (snapshot) {
    self.user = snapshot.val().name
    self.email = snapshot.val().email
  })
```

It might be a scope issue. Try the code above to maintain the scope let’s see if that helps.

Comment: have you tried console.log(snapshot); so we can get an idea of whats there

Answer (score 0):

```
 var edit = ref.child(this.$route.params.id)
 edit.on('value', snapshot => this.user = snapshot.val().name)
 edit.on('value', snapshot => this.email = snapshot.val().email)
```

This works, but exist a form to 'code' better?